# How to prepare a map tiles archive for osmdroid for offline maps?

Tags: android, offline, osmdroid

I prepared [this simple project](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/OSMDroidOfflineDemo) to test the offline map functionality of [osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroids). In the first step I use the Internet connection to download tiles. Everything works as expected. The following code snippet shows the settings for the activity containing the map view.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final GeoPoint BERLIN = new GeoPoint(52.516667, 13.383333);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setClickable(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        mapView.setUseDataConnection(true);
        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);

        IMapController mapViewController = mapView.getController();
        mapViewController.setZoom(15);
        mapViewController.setCenter(BERLIN);
    }

}
```

Now I want to manually supply a archive file containing the tile bitmaps. These are the steps I did to prepare for offline mode:

1. I zip the existing folders on the sdcard which can be found in `/mnt/sdcard/osmdroid/tiles/`.
2. I place the resulting `Mapnik.zip` one level above in `/mnt/sdcard/osmdroid/`.
3. I delete all the cached tiles in `/mnt/sdcard/osmdroid/tiles/Mapnik`.

Now I **turn off** the wireless connection on the phone and restart the application. **No map tile shows up.** Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to use the [tile packager](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/wiki/HowToUsePackager) to create your zip, or [mobile atlas creator](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/wiki/MobileAtlasCreator). However, if you rename all the *.tile files in your zip to *.png, it should work (not tested).

Comment: Nice! I tried so long but never saw that the file extension is `.png.tile`. I **renamed them** to `.png` in the extracted folders and whoop the map appears in **offline mode**. Thanks!